# Application keeps on crashing. It says, Could not create Dart Instance

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine

I am making a new web based ML application using flutter. Whenever i try to run my app, i keep getting an error Could not create Dart VM instance. Must be able to initialize the VM.

I have tried removing some Google-related services from the app that I used before so that it would reflect some change. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class LoaderPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoaderPageState createState() => _LoaderPageState();
}

class _LoaderPageState extends State<LoaderPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _loadImage(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
Widget _loadImage(){
  AssetImage assetimage = AssetImage('images/webdoctor.png');
  Image image =  Image(image: assetimage,);
  return Container(child: image);
  }
}
```

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.3s
Resolving dependencies...                                           6.0s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        24.1s
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                         4.2s
E/flutter ( 5695): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(19)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
E/flutter ( 5695): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(238)] Could not setup VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
E/flutter ( 5695): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(89)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
F/flutter ( 5695): [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(218)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
```

Comment: By `web based` do you mean `flutter web`?

Comment: No, it runs inference on ML data through HTTP request.

Comment: Try `flutter clean` .

Comment: yeah, tried it. Noe change. Had to reinstall flutter again. That temporarily solved the problem

Comment: Seems like the same issue as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793594/flutter-crashed-on-android-6-errorflutter-runtime-dart-vm-data-cc18-vm-sna/70543660#70543660

Answer (score 1):

`Flutter Clean` worked for me.
I was getting this in Android studio while running build from Xcode.
I went to `tools -> flutter -> flutter clean`, then again `tools -> flutter -> open iOS module in Xcode`