# Flutter Crashed on Android 6: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(18)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings

Tags: flutter, crash

We use flutter as a module in our existed app. Recently we find our app crashed when app start, and only happened on Android 6. The crash stack look like this.

```
10-29 08:53:02.851 F/libc    (26633): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 26633 (com.)
10-29 08:53:02.954 F/DEBUG   (  390): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-29 08:53:02.954 F/DEBUG   (  390): Build fingerprint: 'motorola/lux_verizon/lux:6.0.1/MCD24.294-4-6/8:user/release-keys'
10-29 08:53:02.954 F/DEBUG   (  390): Revision: 'p2c0'
10-29 08:53:02.954 F/DEBUG   (  390): ABI: 'arm'
10-29 08:53:02.954 F/DEBUG   (  390): pid: 26633, tid: 26633, name: com.  >>> com. <<<
10-29 08:53:02.954 F/DEBUG   (  390): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
10-29 08:53:02.988 F/DEBUG   (  390): Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(264)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
10-29 08:53:02.988 F/DEBUG   (  390): '
10-29 08:53:02.989 F/DEBUG   (  390):     r0 00000000  r1 00006809  r2 00000006  r3 b6fb1b7c
10-29 08:53:02.989 F/DEBUG   (  390):     r4 b6fb1b84  r5 b6fb1b34  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
10-29 08:53:02.989 F/DEBUG   (  390):     r8 be8ca9a4  r9 be8cb4e8  sl be8cb89c  fp 8f7ea810
10-29 08:53:02.989 F/DEBUG   (  390):     ip 00000006  sp be8c9e90  lr b6d371cd  pc b6d395c8  cpsr 400f0010
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390): 
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390): backtrace:
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390):     #00 pc 000445c8  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390):     #01 pc 000421c9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390):     #02 pc 0001bb1f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390):     #03 pc 00018cc1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390):     #04 pc 00016880  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
10-29 08:53:02.994 F/DEBUG   (  390):     #05 pc 00024a3f  /data/app/com.-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk (offset 0x144c000)
10-29 08:53:04.084 W/ActivityManager( 2082):   Force finishing activity com./com.example.sdk.splash.SplashActivity
10-29 08:53:04.084 F/DEBUG   (  390): 
10-29 08:53:04.084 F/DEBUG   (  390): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
```

```
10-29 09:02:18.927 I/Finsky  (30199): [1718] ose.g(22): Successfully applied new configurations for package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
10-29 09:02:18.928 I/Finsky  (30199): [1715] ose.h(1): Triggered update for experiment package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
10-29 09:02:19.035 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:19.058 E/flutter (30397): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(18)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
10-29 09:02:19.058 E/flutter (30397): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(247)] Could not setup VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
10-29 09:02:19.059 E/flutter (30397): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(84)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
10-29 09:02:19.059 F/flutter (30397): [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(264)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
10-29 09:02:19.060 F/libc    (30397): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30397 (com.)
```

It's not easy to reproduce this crash. We try to install our app through play store, and we see this crash, it will crash when app start. But after a while it doesn't crash again. We try a lot device which system is Android 6(6.0.1),it all works well. But play store shows this crash still here.

Does anyone have this problem?

All stack is here:

```
10-29 09:02:14.818 I/ActivityManager( 2082): Start proc 30397:com./u0a293 for activity com./com.example.sdk.splash.SplashActivity
10-29 09:02:14.836 D/ProcSpeedReader( 4065): Failed to read freq stats from null
10-29 09:02:14.854 W/ResourceType(30397): ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 3933, previously 3943
10-29 09:02:14.854 W/ResourceType(30397): ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 4845, previously 4867
10-29 09:02:14.854 W/ResourceType(30397): ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 60, previously 58
10-29 09:02:14.854 W/ResourceType(30397): ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 225, previously 1157
10-29 09:02:15.199 I/DM._hotpatch(30397): hotpatch sdk version: 3.10.1.7.7.2
10-29 09:02:15.205 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Binder,pkg is :com.,flag is :128
10-29 09:02:15.205 D/DM._hotpatch(30397): insert hack = false
10-29 09:02:15.214 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Binder,pkg is :com.,flag is :0
10-29 09:02:15.317 W/com.asurion.android.verizon.vms(27872): type=1400 audit(0.0:6202): avc: denied { search } for uid=10069 comm=546F704170704D6F6E69746F72202D name="3445" dev="proc" ino=273985 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-29 09:02:15.317 W/com.asurion.android.verizon.vms(27872): type=1400 audit(0.0:6203): avc: denied { search } for uid=10069 comm=546F704170704D6F6E69746F72202D name="3445" dev="proc" ino=273985 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-29 09:02:15.504 I/art     (30397): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3026(259KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 38% free, 25MB/41MB, paused 5.300ms total 28.158ms
10-29 09:02:15.876 D/BaseApplication(30397): xcrash anr check open status:true
10-29 09:02:15.876 D/BaseApplication(30397): xcrash anr check open success
10-29 09:02:15.878 W/AppCrashInterceptor(30397): hookActivityThread success 
10-29 09:02:16.057 I/SFPerfTracer(  372):      triggers: (rate: 0:2) (5670 sw vsyncs) (0 skipped) (120:49242 vsyncs) (122:58386)
10-29 09:02:16.138 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.145 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.151 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:16.300 W/ResourceType(30397): ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 67, previously 69
10-29 09:02:16.319 W/System  (30397): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000055/n/armeabi-v7a
10-29 09:02:16.319 W/System  (30397): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000055/n/armeabi
10-29 09:02:16.324 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.323 W/com.asurion.android.verizon.vms(27872): type=1400 audit(0.0:6204): avc: denied { search } for uid=10069 comm=546F704170704D6F6E69746F72202D name="3445" dev="proc" ino=276017 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-29 09:02:16.323 W/com.asurion.android.verizon.vms(27872): type=1400 audit(0.0:6205): avc: denied { search } for uid=10069 comm=546F704170704D6F6E69746F72202D name="3445" dev="proc" ino=276017 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-29 09:02:16.330 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.330 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.330 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.333 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.384 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.420 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Binder,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:16.438 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:16.486 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:16.488 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.517 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:16.527 D/WifiService( 2082): New client listening to asynchronous messages
10-29 09:02:16.550 I/FA      (30397): App measurement initialized, version: 44007
10-29 09:02:16.550 I/FA      (30397): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-29 09:02:16.551 I/FA      (30397): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
10-29 09:02:16.551 I/FA      (30397):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.
10-29 09:02:16.558 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:16.661 D/BoundBrokerSvc( 7123): onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
10-29 09:02:16.661 D/BoundBrokerSvc( 7123): Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
10-29 09:02:16.678 I/art     (30397): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 75603(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 27(540KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 35MB/41MB, paused 3.395ms total 100.981ms
10-29 09:02:16.727 D/audio_hw_primary(  394): out_standby: enter: stream (0xb807c2f8) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)
10-29 09:02:16.730 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:16.745 D/ApmPool—(30397): active count = 1; task count = 2
10-29 09:02:16.747 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:16.750 D/PreLoaders(30397): preloadSp time is :9
10-29 09:02:16.752 I/ApmServiceManager(30397): redirectLogStreams
10-29 09:02:16.811 D/hardware_info(  394): hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
10-29 09:02:16.852 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:17.444 I/art     (30397): Thread[1,tid=30397,Native,Thread*=0xb81dbd60,peer=0x737082a0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libwsg.so"
10-29 09:02:17.458 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:17.462 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:17.462 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:17.463 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:17.471 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Binder,pkg is :com.android.vending,flag is :0
10-29 09:02:17.477 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:17.480 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Binder,pkg is :com.android.vending,flag is :8256
10-29 09:02:17.482 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Binder,pkg is :com.google.android.gms,flag is :64
10-29 09:02:17.552 W/linker  (30397): /data/app/com.-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0xf20
10-29 09:02:17.657 I/ThermalEngine(  418): Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg from  override
10-29 09:02:17.657 E/ThermalEngine(  418): override_notify: SS mode 0 override
10-29 09:02:17.658 I/Thermal-Lib( 4747): Thermal-Lib-Client: Client request sent
10-29 09:02:17.675 I/ShortcutBadger(30199): Checking if platform supports badge counters, attempt 1/3.
10-29 09:02:17.684 I/Finsky  (30199): [1711] eqn.run(29): Initializing the instant apps module.
10-29 09:02:17.697 I/ShortcutBadger(30199): Checking if platform supports badge counters, attempt 2/3.
10-29 09:02:17.705 I/ShortcutBadger(30199): Checking if platform supports badge counters, attempt 3/3.
10-29 09:02:17.706 I/Finsky  (30199): [1719] ose.h(1): Triggered update for experiment package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
10-29 09:02:17.707 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:17.713 W/ShortcutBadger(30199): Badge counter seems not supported in this platform: unable to resolve intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE (has extras) }
10-29 09:02:17.759 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:17.759 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:17.810 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Binder,pkg is :com.android.vending,flag is :128
10-29 09:02:17.841 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:17.859 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.015 D/ApmPool—(30397): active count = 2; task count = 3
10-29 09:02:18.030 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.088 D/ApmPool—(30397): active count = 2; task count = 4
10-29 09:02:18.131 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.android.vending,flag is :8256,cache flag is :8256
10-29 09:02:18.131 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.google.android.gms,flag is :64,cache flag is :64
10-29 09:02:18.134 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.android.vending,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.136 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.android.vending,flag is :8256,cache flag is :8256
10-29 09:02:18.136 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.google.android.gms,flag is :64,cache flag is :64
10-29 09:02:18.330 W/com.asurion.android.verizon.vms(27872): type=1400 audit(0.0:6206): avc: denied { search } for uid=10069 comm=546F704170704D6F6E69746F72202D name="3445" dev="proc" ino=276017 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-29 09:02:18.330 W/com.asurion.android.verizon.vms(27872): type=1400 audit(0.0:6207): avc: denied { search } for uid=10069 comm=546F704170704D6F6E69746F72202D name="3445" dev="proc" ino=276017 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-29 09:02:18.354 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.359 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.362 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.488 I/art     (30397): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8591(464KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 41MB/41MB, paused 11.594ms total 26.706ms
10-29 09:02:18.491 I/Finsky  (30199): [1719] osm.c(1): Regular flags synced
10-29 09:02:18.492 I/Finsky  (30199): [1719] pqp.s(3): Writing flags config, size 1.
10-29 09:02:18.493 I/Finsky  (30199): [1719] pqp.s(3): Started writing experiment flags into file [OLHc9oYTV-NaLIe_OkJtf4LG_fPlCS82vO15jjWcCO4].
10-29 09:02:18.511 I/Finsky  (30199): [1719] pqp.s(17): Finished writing experiment flags into file [OLHc9oYTV-NaLIe_OkJtf4LG_fPlCS82vO15jjWcCO4].
10-29 09:02:18.524 I/Finsky  (30199): [1719] ose.g(22): Successfully applied new configurations for package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
10-29 09:02:18.525 I/Finsky  (30199): [1718] ose.h(1): Triggered update for experiment package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
10-29 09:02:18.562 I/art     (30397): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 719(89KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 42MB/42MB, paused 7.132ms total 25.061ms
10-29 09:02:18.634 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :16512,cache flag is :16512
10-29 09:02:18.639 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.android.vending,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.738 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:18.886 I/Finsky  (30199): [1718] osm.c(1): Regular flags synced
10-29 09:02:18.888 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getPackageInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :0,cache flag is :0
10-29 09:02:18.896 I/Finsky  (30199): [1718] pqp.s(3): Writing flags config, size 1.
10-29 09:02:18.898 I/Finsky  (30199): [1718] pqp.s(3): Started writing experiment flags into file [U_VxB5TkGKVLTJYoMWfHZF55KpJiC3UMsFQiwWDBuvg].
10-29 09:02:18.916 I/Finsky  (30199): [1718] pqp.s(17): Finished writing experiment flags into file [U_VxB5TkGKVLTJYoMWfHZF55KpJiC3UMsFQiwWDBuvg].
10-29 09:02:18.921 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:18.927 I/Finsky  (30199): [1718] ose.g(22): Successfully applied new configurations for package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
10-29 09:02:18.928 I/Finsky  (30199): [1715] ose.h(1): Triggered update for experiment package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
10-29 09:02:19.035 I/Apm_PackageManager(30397): getApplicationInfo from Cache,pkg is :com.,flag is :128,cache flag is :128
10-29 09:02:19.058 E/flutter (30397): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(18)] VM snapshot invalid and could not be inferred from settings.
10-29 09:02:19.058 E/flutter (30397): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(247)] Could not setup VM data to bootstrap the VM from.
10-29 09:02:19.059 E/flutter (30397): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(84)] Could not create Dart VM instance.
10-29 09:02:19.059 F/flutter (30397): [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(264)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
10-29 09:02:19.060 F/libc    (30397): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30397 (com.)
10-29 09:02:19.117 F/DEBUG   (  390): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
```

Comment: [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on macOS 11.4 20F71, locale zh-Hans-CN)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.5.1)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Have you try to add "android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false" to your android gradle.properties as suggested by flutter docs? https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release

Comment: I didn't add this before, I'll give it a try, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

That is related to known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147096055. From the link:

> "If you are a Flutter users, here's what you can do to fix this issue:
>
> 1. If you build an App Bundle
>    Edit android/gradle.properties and add the flag: android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
> 2. If you build an APK.
>    Ensure android/app/src/AndroidManifest.xml doesn't set `android:extractNativeLibs=false` in the `<application>` tag."

I myself tried and solved the issue with my flutter app. Adding android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false flag solved the issue on BlackBerry DTEK STH100-2 Android 6.0.1. The app was crashing only on release mode and only after installing from play store as an app bundle. Adb logcat was giving could not start Dart VM fatal error.